# Rider: change documentation comments template

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, code-documentation, rider, comments

Is it possible to change template for "summary" comments in Rider? When I'm typing "///" it generates summary comments like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <param name="world"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool Hello(string name, int world) {}
```

But I don't need documenting params and other. I just would be happy to have only summary block:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
private bool Hello(string name, int world) {}
```

Comment: I found a partial solution to the question. I created "Live Template" with my summary template, which is activated by typing "// + Tab".